Issue with cannot set headers after they are sent to the client - nodejs, mongoose
Im working on a settings page with 4 input values on the front end.
I have only one table in the db that i want to update correspond to the input value.
Right now im testing this endpoint in postman , lets start with the function itself:
updateController:
exports.updateSettings = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Execute the query and await the result
    const data = await Settings.findOne({}, { _id: 1 }).exec();

    const settingsId = data._id;
    const updatedValue = req.body.newValue;
    const fieldToUpdate = req.body.fieldToUpdate;

    // Update the settings using the settingsId
    await Settings.findByIdAndUpdate(settingsId, {
      $set: { [fieldToUpdate]: updatedValue },
    });

    console.log("AFTER FINDBYIDANDUPDATE"); // im not getting to this part
    res.status(200).json({ message: "update-settings-success" });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error updating settings:", err);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "failed-update-settings" });
  }
};

Settings schema:
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const settingsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
createdAt: {
type: Date,
default: Date.now,
},
minBookingLen: {
type: Number,
required: true,
},
maxBookingLen: {
type: Number,
required: true,
},
maxGuestsPerBooking: {
type: Number,
required: true,
},
breakfastPrice: {
type: Number,
required: true,
},
});

const Settings = mongoose.model("Setting", settingsSchema);

module.exports = Settings;

The route:
router.patch("/update-settings", updateSettings.updateSettings);

Ill just mention that the endpoint are connected and working just the thing is that when i on of the values lets say breakfastPrice and the  error message im getting:
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
Im expecting to show the update-settings-success message but i guess something is off with how im using the findByIdAndUpdate or maybe nesting both requests is wrong.

ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT occurs when your code attempts to send more than one response to the same request.  The code you show does not appear to have that issue so there's either more code executing on this request (like perhaps some middleware that is also trying to send a response) or the problem is actually occurring in some other request handler, not this one.

FYI, do you really need .exec() with .findOne()?  The doc doesn't seem to require that.

Can i share the front end part maybe you can see the issue there ?

Are you getting here : console.error("Error updating settings:", err); If so, what is the error message from err.

Im getting 200 and after 10 sec i get the console.log("getSettings err: ", err);
and the log i get from the backend is:
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Please show the code that has console.log("getSettings err: ", err); in it.


error after 10 sec: This time is with respect to bufferTimeoutMS, reference https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#bufferTimeoutMS. It means the connection is not getting established. Can you please do a unit testing for connection status alone and see it is getting connected.


If you're getting the error 10 seconds after the request has finished, then there's either some middleware that is still functioning on this request (after you've sent the response) or there is some other request that is being processed that you aren't aware of.
You can instrument your code to see exactly which requests are coming in by adding this middleware as the very first request handler in your Express code (before any other middleware):
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`Incoming request: ${req.method}: ${req.url}`);
    next();
});

P.S. I know this isn't a finished answer yet, but I needed to show you some multi-line code to add for debugging purposes so I had to put that in an answer.
